# Open another view through controller from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view with a jQuery Click. I want to send an ID to a controller and open a view.

```
   j("#jstree_demo_div").on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
            console.log(data.node.a_attr.href); // Node value

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("FilterCategories", "FileUploads")',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    /* alert(data); */
                },
                statusCode: {
                    404: function (content) { alert('cannot find resource' + data.node.a_attr.href); },
                    500: function (content) { alert('internal server error' + data.node.a_attr.href); }
                },
                error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
                    // handle status === "timeout"
                    // handle other errors
                }
            });

        });
```

I can see the page in the alert if I uncomment  `alert(data);` but how do I open my controller and return my view?

My controller

```
public ActionResult CategoryId(/*int? CategoryId*/) 
{
    //Something with CategoryId
    return View();
}
```

And I have a view CategoryId in Views folder. Guess I need something more on `success: function (data)`

Comment: So what you're asking is how to send that `CategoryId` to the server in your AJAX call?

Comment: How I can open my controller and navigate to the view. I want to open the view CategoryId through my  CategoryId Action. Right now nothing happens when I click but I can see the page in an alert if I uncomment that in success.

Comment: What do you mean _"navigate to the view."_? Ajax calls stay on the same page. Do you want to update the existing page to add the content returned by you controller method?

Comment: you need to [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the `data` to an element on your page - so in your success, you would have something like this: `$('#element').append(data)`

Comment: In my eyes there is no need to do that with an Ajax request other than a slight SPA feeling...

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar earlier today and found that this did the trick:

```
success: function(response){
                document.write(response);
            }
```